# Confusion on an application of the law of total probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am trying to get a grasp of the law of total probability, which I only discovered this morning. I have been toying with a problem in order to do so.

> *Stiuation*. Imagine we draw a series of numbers from a standard uniform distribution. Whenever the sum of those numbers surpasses $\alpha$, an arbitrary criteria within $[0, 1]$, we stop the game.

I've been toying with finding the probability of the game *not* stopping on the different $i$th draws. The trivial probability is $P(a_1) = \alpha$, the probability that the game does not stop after the first draw. But as we add more draws, it gets more tricky. I want to avoid convolutions, so I thought apply the law of total probability as follows.

If $a_i$ is the event of the game not stopping on the $i$th draw, or equivalently that the first $i$ draws draws did not add up over $\alpha$, then $a_2$ implies the occurrence of $a_1$.  Observe that the probability of drawing a number $x$ that keeps us in the range
$[0, \alpha]$ assuming that we have already drawn some $y \in [0, \alpha]$ on
the first step is, according to the law of total probability,

\begin{align*}
    P(a_2) &= \int_\mathbb{R} P(x \in [0, \alpha - y] \mid y \in [0, \alpha])P(y \in [0,
    \alpha]) dy \\ 
    &= \int_{0}^\alpha (\alpha - y)(1) dy \\ 
    &= \frac{\alpha^2}{2}
\end{align*}

So far, I think the application is correct. Here, $P(a_2) = \alpha/2$ is a probability functional to $\alpha$. My question comes from the fact that any event $a_i$ is conditioned on $a_{i-1}$, so I thought of the following application of the law of total probability.

\begin{align*}
    P(a_3) &= \int_{0}^\alpha (\alpha - y)\frac{y^2}{2}dy =
    \frac{\alpha^4}{24}\\ 
    P(a_4) &= \int_0^\alpha (\alpha - y) \frac{y^4}{24} dy = \frac{\alpha^6}{720} \\ 
&\ldots
.\end{align*}

Namely, we are applying the same principles we described for $P(a_1)$, but we are using $P(a_{i-1})$ (in terms of $y$) as the probability upon which we condition each $P(a_i)$.

What confuses me is that each $P(a_i)$ is a not a probability distribution, but a specific probability value that is, incidentally, a function of $\alpha$. So I am unsure of whether one can condition the total probability over them, treating them as a function over the integration variable $y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addendum added to respond to the comment/question of lafinur.

---

I agree that your approach is problematic, because your integration formulas are expressed in terms of the value $~y,~$ which is itself a variable.

I think that this problem is best attacked via recursion.

For $~\alpha \in [0,1], ~n \in \Bbb{Z^+}, $ 
let $~f(\alpha,n)~$ denote the probability that $~n~$ random numbers, drawn from $~[0,1]~$ have a sum that does not exceed $~\alpha.$

Then, in general,

$$f(\alpha,n+1) = \frac{\int_0^\alpha f(\alpha - t,n) ~dt}{\int_0^1 1 ~dt} = \frac{\int_0^\alpha f(\alpha - t,n) ~dt}{1} = \int_0^\alpha f(\alpha - t,n) ~dt. \tag1 $$

(1) above takes some explaining.  The numerator has the variable $~t~$ range from $~0~$ to $~\alpha.$  For each such value $~t,~$ the probability associated with that value is the probability that $~n~$ random terms do not have their sum exceed $~\alpha - t.$

In (1) above, when considering the numerator, it is implicit that $~t~$ is actually ranging from $~0~$ to $~1,~$ with the understanding that for each value of $~t > \alpha,~$ the corresponding probability associated with that value is $~0.~$

In (1) above, the denominator is used to *normalize* the numerator, so that if the probability function in the numerator was instead equal to $~1,~$ for each value of $~t \in [0,1],~$ then the overall fraction would equal $~1.$

---

Applying the expression in (1) above, you have that

$$f(\alpha,1) = \alpha \implies $$

$$f(\alpha,2) = \int_0^\alpha [\alpha - t] ~dt 
= \left.\alpha t - \frac{t^2}{2}\right\rvert_0^\alpha
= \frac{\alpha^2}{2} \implies 
$$

$$f(\alpha,3) = \int_0^\alpha \left[ \frac{~(\alpha - t)^2}{2} ~\right] ~dt$$

$$= \left.\frac{~- ~(\alpha - t)^3}{3!}
\right\rvert_0^\alpha = \frac{\alpha^3}{3!}.
$$

This leads to the hypothesis that

$$f(\alpha,n) = \frac{\alpha^n}{n!},$$

which can be proven by induction.

That is:

$$f(\alpha,n+1) = \int_0^\alpha \left[ \frac{~(\alpha - t)^n}{n!} ~\right] ~dt$$

$$= \left.\frac{~- ~(\alpha - t)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}
\right\rvert_0^\alpha = \frac{\alpha^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}.
$$

---

**Addendum**

> Could you elaborate on the recursive formula for $~f~?$

Given that you are going to select $~n+1,~$ random numbers from $~[0,1],~$ define a random variable $X$ so that :

- $X = 1 ~: ~$ the $~(n+1)~$ numbers have a sum that does not exceed $~\alpha.~$
- $X = 0 ~: ~$ the $~(n+1)~$ numbers have a sum that does exceed $~\alpha.~$

Then $~f(\alpha,n+1) = E(X).~$

For $~t,\alpha \in [0,1], ~n \in \Bbb{Z^+},$ 
let $~p(\alpha,t,n+1)~$ denote the **conditional probability** that $~(n+1)~$ numbers have a sum that does not exceed $~\alpha,~$ 
**given** that :

- The very first of the $~(n+1)~$ numbers happens to equal $~t.~$
- The other $~(n)~$ numbers are taken at random from $~[0,1].$

Then,

$$E(X) = \frac{\int_0^1 
[ ~1 \times p(\alpha,t,n+1)~] ~dt}{\int_0^1 1 ~dt}. \tag2 $$

In the numerator of (2) above, the expression $~[ ~1 \times p(\alpha,t,n+1) ~] ~$ represents the expected value that will be assigned to the variable $~X~$ for a specific value of $~t,~$ where $~t~$ ranges from $~0~$ through $~1.$

So, since the numerator of (2) above is being divided by the *normalizing* denominator, the expression in (2) above represents the overall expected value of $~X.$

Now, suppose that $~\alpha < t \leq 1.~$ 
It is now impossible for the $~(n+1)~$ numbers, which include the number $~t,~$ to have a sum $~\leq \alpha.$

Therefore, when $~\alpha < t \leq 1,~$ 
you have that

$$~p(\alpha,t,n+1) = 0.$$

Suppose instead that $~0 \leq t \leq \alpha.~$ 
Then the $~(n+1)~$ numbers will have a sum that does not exceed $~\alpha~$ 
if and only if 
the $~(n)~$ numbers, with $~t~$ excluded, have a sum that does not exceed $~\alpha - t.$

Therefore, when $~0 \leq t \leq \alpha,~$ you have that

$$~p(\alpha,t,n+1) = f(\alpha - t, ~n).$$

This explains the equation:

$$f(\alpha,n+1) = \frac{\int_0^\alpha f(\alpha - t,n) ~dt}{\int_0^1 1 ~dt}.$$

Comment: Could you elaborate on how did you come up with the recursive formula for $f$? The relationship between the probability for the $n+1$th and the $n$th draws is not immediate to my beginner eyes.

Comment: @lafinur See the Addendum that I have just added to the end of my answer.

Comment: Your answer was excellent, and I appreciate it. I have arrived at the same result as you using the law of total probability. I will edit my question to show that for the sake of anyone who might enter here with doubts concerning that law.